# SwiftUI Textfield not responding to State variable

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I would like to have a TextField that will display units after a number, such as % or inches or cm.  However, when you tap on the field, the value should change to not have the units so that the user can edit easily.

The code below creates two TextFields that interact.  The top one works with a number.  It is the behavior of the bottom TextField that I am interested in.  When one taps on that field, it does not remove the formatting at the end of the number.  If one then taps on the other field, the conversion of the text to an integer fails, and the code substitutes in a zero.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sValue = ""
    @State private var score = 22

    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()

    func updateSvalue(_ text: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sValue = text
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Value", value: $score, formatter: formatter)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .frame(maxWidth: 120)
            TextField("Value", text: $sValue,
                      onEditingChanged: { (isBegin) in
                if isBegin {
                    // Remove % format -- not working without DispatchQueue...
                    let next = "\(score)"
                    print("Begins: next=\(next)")
                    sValue = next
                } else {
                    score = Int(sValue) ?? 0
                    let next = "\(score)%"
                    print("Finishes: next=\(next)")
                    sValue = next
                }
            },
                      onCommit: {
                score = Int(sValue) ?? 0
                let next = "\(score)%"
                print("onCommit: next=\(next)")
                sValue = next
            })
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .frame(maxWidth: 120)
        }
        .onAppear{
            sValue = "\(score)%" }
        .onChange(of: score, perform: {newValue in
            sValue = "\(newValue)%"
        })
    }
}
```

I discovered that if I replace the lines of:

```
sValue = next
```

with a call to updateSvalue(), which dispatches setting sValue to the main queue, then things will actually work:

```
updateSvalue(next)
```

I would appreciate comments on why changing sValue works in some parts of the code and not others?  Are there problems with using DispatchQueue? Other approaches to do this?